# Multiple short rules pattern matching algorithm

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching

As the title advances, we would like to get some advice on the fastest algorithm available for pattern matching with the following constrains:

Long dictionary: 256

Short but not fixed length rules (from 1 to 3 or 4 bytes depth at most)

Small (150) number of rules (if 3 bytes) or moderate (~1K) if 4

Better performance than current AC-DFA used in Snort or than AC-DFA-Split again used by Snort

Software based (recent COTS systems like E3 of E5)
Ideally would like to employ some SIMD / SSE stuff due to the fact that currently they are 128 bit wide and in near future they will be 256 in opposition to CPU's 64

We started this project by prefiltering Snort AC with algorithm shown on Sigmatch paper but sadly the results have not been that impressive (~12% improvement when compiling with GCC but none with ICC)

Afterwards we tried to exploit new pattern matching capabilities present in SSE 4.2 through IPP libraries but no performance gain at all (guess doing it directly in machine code would be better but for sure more complex)

So back to the original idea. Right now we are working along the lines of Head Body Segmentation AC but are aware unless we replace the proposed AC-DFA for the head side will be very hard to get improved performance, but at least would be able to support much more rules without a significant performance drop

We are aware using bit parallelism ideas use a lot of memory for long patterns but precisely the problem scope has been reduce to 3 or 4 bytes long at most thus making them a feasible alternative

We have found Nedtries in particular but would like to know what do you guys think or if there are better alternatives

Ideally the source code would be in C and under an open source license.

---

IMHO, our idea was to search for something that moved 1 byte at a time to cope with different sizes but do so very efficiently by taking advantage of most parallelism possible by using SIMD / SSE and also trying to be the less branchy as possible

I don't know if doing this in a bit wise manner or byte wise

---

Back to a proper keyboard :D

In essence, most algorithms are not correctly exploiting current hardware capabilities nor limitations. They are very cache inneficient, very branchy not to say they dont exploit capabilities now present in COTS CPUs that allow you to have certain level of paralelism (SIMD, SSE, ...)

This is preciselly what we are seeking for, an algorithm (or an implementation of an already existing algorithm) that properly considers all that, with the advantag of not trying to cover all rule lengths, just short ones

For example, I have seen some papers on NFAs claming that this days their performance could be on pair to DFAs with much less memory requirements due to proper cache efficiency, enhanced paralelism, etc

Comment: http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~mac/Articles-PDF/CCGLPR99ipl-multipat.pdf?

Comment: http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~sahni/papers/multipatternCell.pdf?

Comment: Hi Baxter, thanks for prompt reply. I will read them both ASAP but just a fast glimpse of the first one seems to target lengths not too small (in the paper m value) and this is not our case (m=1). That is the problem of all windowing or skipping algorithms, our min length value is too short killing their supra linear performance

Comment: Sorry for dual commenting. Btw, when I said supralinear I meant sublinear :)

Comment: You can just delete the duplicate comment.  I understood sublinear :-}

Comment: To the OP: do you mean that the maximal pattern length is 4, and there are about 256 patterns to be matched?

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at:
http://www.slideshare.net/bouma2
Support of 1 and 2 bytes is similar to what Baxter wrote above. Nevertheless, it would help if you could provide the number of single-byte and double-byte strings you expect to be in the DB, and the kind of traffic you are expecting to process (Internet, corporate etc.) - after all, too many single-byte strings may end up in a match for every byte. The idea of Bouma2 is to allow the incorporation of occurrence statistics into the preprocessing stage, thereby reducing the false-positives rate.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are already using hi-performance pattern matching.  Unless you have some clever new algorithm, or can point to some statistical bias in the data or your rules, its going to be hard to speed up the raw algorithms.

You might consider treating *pairs* of characters as pattern match elements.  This will make the branching factor of the state machine huge but you presumably don't care about RAM.   This might buy you a factor of two.

When running out of steam algorithmically, people often resort to careful hand coding in assembler including clever use of the SSE instructions.  A trick that might be helpful to handle unique sequences whereever found is to do a series of comparisons against the elements and forming a boolean result by anding/oring rather than conditional branching, because branches are expensive.  The SSE instructions might be helpful here, although their alignment requirements might force you to replicate them 4 or 8 times.

If the strings you are searching are long, you might distribute subsets of rules to seperate CPUs (threads).   Partitioning the rules might be tricky.

Comment: Hi, I have seen some papers about the supradictionary idea, but my concern is that some patterns are just 1 byte long

Comment: A way to look at "1 byte" patterns is they are *2* byte patterns where the second character is a wildcard.

Comment: Mmm, that's right but also would mean entering regular expression realm instead of exact pattern matching. Either way I don't dual byte automata with the huge ram requirement would be nice for cache efficiency :( Sorry I'm doing comments from iPhone and for sure seems not the most friendly tool for this :(